# How can I list global variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, global-variables

How can I see a list of what global variables are defined in MATLAB? (I am using R2009a).

I have hunted unfruitfully for this on Google and SO, so apologies if it has been asked before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [WHO/WHOS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/who.html) commands can show you just the global variables:

```
who global   %# Shows just the variable names
whos global  %# Shows variable information, like size, class, etc.
```

You can also get the variable names/information returned in a variable instead of displayed on the screen:

```
names = who('global');  %# A cell array of variable names
data = whos('global');  %# A structure array of variable information
```

Answer (score 4):

If you type `whos` at the command line Matlab will list all currently defined variables in your workspace.  The last column of output is headed 'Attributes', global variables have the attribute 'global'.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me! There are no globals in my the 'whos' list, yet many functions are clearly storing globals.

Comment: @SanjayManohar This only works when the global variable is added to the current workspace using `global varname`